# How to find the default branch of Repository - Bitbucket Cloud API

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-cloud

I went through the complete API documentation of **The Bitbucket Cloud Rest API**:

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-repositories/#api-group-repositories

But I did not found any way or API to get the default branch of Bitbucket Cloud Repository.

Could anyone help me with this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST API has a [filter](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/intro/#filtering) for all branches of a repository, its response has a property named `isDefault`

```
curl -s -u $BITBUCKET_KEY $BITBUCKET_URL/rest/api/latest/projects/$PROJECT/repos/$REPO/branches?limit=100 | jq -r '.values[]'
```

```json
{
  "id": "refs/heads/master",
  "displayId": "master",
  "type": "BRANCH",
  "latestCommit": "c2a944ba03ea7c1ab07b3159660c69647229704e",
  "latestChangeset": "c2a944ba03ea7c1ab07b3159660c69647229704e",
  "isDefault": true
}
{
  "id": "refs/heads/release/1.3.5",
  "displayId": "release/1.3.5",
  "type": "BRANCH",
  "latestCommit": "a835d28c8f828610fcc4f0f463b99c4a75039aef",
  "latestChangeset": "a835d28c8f828610fcc4f0f463b99c4a75039aef",
  "isDefault": false
}
```

A listing can be shown with:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Get branches in a BitBucket repo
set -euo pipefail

REPO=$1
PROJECT='MYTEAM'

## url of  branches in a repo
BITBUCKET_URL="https://bitbucket.example.com/rest/api/latest/projects/$PROJECT/repos/$REPO/branches?limit=100"

# Check BITBUCKET_URL with a http HEAD request
OUT=$(curl --fail --head -u "$BITBUCKET_KEY" "$BITBUCKET_URL" 2>&1)
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
   echo "Error: $OUT"| tail -1
   exit $?
fi

# Query the JSON output of the request
JSON=$(curl -s -u "$BITBUCKET_KEY" "$BITBUCKET_URL" 2>&1)
echo "$JSON" | jq -r '.values[] | .displayId'
```

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/intro/#filtering

Comment: could you also share the reference for it

Answer (score 0):

The answer from bbaassssiiee is for Bitbucket Server, not for Bitbucket Cloud.

For Bitbucket Cloud, query the repo details and access $.mainbranch
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-repositories/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-get

The example response from the current version of the documentation includes the mainbranch property but only subproperty "type" ($.mainbranch.type). In actual responses the "type" value is "branch" (obviously) but you also have $.mainbranch.name which is what you are looking for.